# Rails Shopping Cart Not Adding and/or Showing the Right Products

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a very basic shopping cart through a youtube tutorial.  The problem I'm having is that, although the link to add the product exists and redirects to the cart without raising an exception, it always adds and shows the first product in the list (and if I destroy that first product, then the next one shows up).

I know the problem lies in the add method, which does not store multiple product ids as it should.

cart_controller.rb

```
class CartController < ApplicationController

def add
id = params[:id]
if session[:cart] then
  cart = session[:cart]
else
  session[:cart] = {}
  cart = session[:cart]
end

if  cart[:id] then
    cart[:id] = cart[:id] + 1
else
    cart[:id] = 1
end
redirect_to cart_url

end

def clearCart
session[:cart] = nil
redirect_to cart_url
end


def index
  if session[:cart] then
    @cart = session[:cart]
  else
    @cart = {}
  end
end

end
```

cart index.html

```
<%= link_to 'Empty Your Cart', cart_clear_path %>


 <% @cart.each do | id, quantity| %>
  <% product = Product.find_by(id) %>
  <ul>
    <li><%= link_to product.title, product %></li>

  </ul>

<% end %>
```

products index.html

```
`<% @products.each do |product| %>`
    <tr>  
    <td><%= product.title %></td>
    <td><%= product.description %></td>
    <td><%= product.image_url %></td>
    <td><%= product.price %></td>
            <td><%= product.category %></td>
                    <td><%= product.subcategory %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', product %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm:      'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    <td><a href="/cart/<%= product.id %>">Add to Cart</a></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself.  Indeed, the add method held the problem.  The :id param was already stored in the id variable.

```
if  cart[id] then
  cart[id] = cart[id] + 1
else
  cart[id] = 1
```

Also modified the product variable.

```
product = Product.find_by(id: id)
```